# Cordova. Прослушивание музыки в фоне

Tags: javascript, android, html5, cordova

Здравствуйте! Я разрабатываю приложение используя обертку Cordova. В приложении нужно будет прослушивать музыку. У меня такой вопрос: можно ли сделать так, чтобы музыка играла в фоне. То есть, если ты свернул приложение, оно остается на шторке, как у ВК. Если можно, то дайте, пожалуйста, советы.

Comment: я думаю, что это очень непросто (читай *невозможно*) при помощи Cordova

Comment: @metalurgus А есть что-то подобное: пишешь на HTML, запускаешь как нативное приложение, при это поддерживается музыка в фоне?

Comment: я бы сказал, что ничего, к сожалению... Я знаю, как это сделать на JAVA, но на HTML5 - нет

Comment: @metalurgus А как это делается на Java?